# why the method oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex() costs so much time?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

I've got an entity which has 201 fields(testId,test1...test200) that id is long type and the others are String. And I searched it in Hibernate with the HQL

> this.getTestDao().getHibernateTemplate().find("from Test where testId<=10000")

The thread turned to **spring-hibernate3.jar** then

```
//Method from spring-hibernate3.jar
//org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate
public List find(final String queryString, final Object values[])
        throws DataAccessException
    {
        return (List)execute(new HibernateCallback() {

        public Object doInHibernate(Session session)
            throws HibernateException
        {
            Query queryObject = session.createQuery(queryString);
            prepareQuery(queryObject);
            if(values != null)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
                    queryObject.setParameter(i, values[i]);

            }
            return queryObject.list();
        }
    }
, true);
    }
```

But Java VisualVm(a monitor software in JDK) told me that the  method **oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex()** cost 4404ms for 10 thousand data
.I know Hibernate is slow but it's really unacceptable,'cause it only cost 55ms in sqldeveloper with the same SQL.

I am sure that there is no any exception printed and every fileld is legal.here is the decompiled code **oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex**

```
//Method from oracle10.2 jdbc14.jar
// oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement
int getColumnIndex(String s)
    throws SQLException
{
    if(!describedWithNames)
        synchronized(connection)
        {
            synchronized(this)
            {
                connection.needLine();
                doDescribe(true);
                described = true;
                describedWithNames = true;
            }
        }
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfDefinePositions; i++)
        if(accessors[i].columnName.equalsIgnoreCase(s))
            return i + 1;

    DatabaseError.throwSqlException(6);
    return 0;
}
```

and the image from monitor
[***click to view***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Da16J.jpg)

Thanks everybody,thanks pointing the grammar mistakes if existed.

Comment: What about posting some code then or are we meant to guess the answer?

Comment: Don't use `HIbernateTemplate` there is no need to do so anymore. Also executing a query in sql developer and comparing that to getting a result in hibernate is comparing apples and oranges. Hibernate does a whole lot more converting each row into an object (graph) for instance and creating objects is kind of slow, you say you have 201 fields, 10000 rows which means you are creating 2.000.000 objects (at a minimum). Hibernate doesn't have to be slow, but it generally becomes slow because people are using it wrong or or wrong expectations.

Comment: What I coded is only the HQL,then it called the "find" method in Hibernate,and finally it went to "getColumnIndex" method.I edit the question again,hope it helped.

Comment: No you did a whole lot more, you created an entity, you created a mapping. However you seem not to understand (or fail to acknowledge) that hibernate does a whole lot more then your sql developer tool. It isn't simply a matter of returning the result it does conversion, type checking and creates a whole lot of objects.Also hibernate 3 why are you stil using that, the most recent version is 5.1 and 3 has been abandoned for years already.

Comment: Why are you using such an outdated driver? `ojdbc14.jar` is inteded for Java **1.4** - are you really still using Java 1.4? And are you really still using Oracle 10?

Comment: As far as I can see Hibernate calls `OracleStatement.getColumnIndex()` when retrieving a row for each column (via `nullSafeGet()`) and does this all over again **for each and every row**. As `OracleStatement.getColumnIndex()` seems to be quite costly when a lot of columns are involved this is very expensive and comes on top of the overhead of creating objects etc. This would not be necessary if the column index would just be cached after determining it once and only once at the beginning of creating the result set. Like the OP I am interested if there is a way around this.

Comment: BTW even the current Hibernate code on GitHub seems still to do just the same: `nullSafeGet()` still takes strings with the column name instead of the column index or an object wrapping the column index.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue.    We use Hibernate to load a very "wide" table (~200 columns) into objects.   For each row in the result set, Hibernate will try to "extract" the value in each column *using its name*.    To do this, it calls the "OracleStatement.getColumnIndex" method (above).   This stupid method looks up the index by iterating through all the fields field... trying to see if the name of the column matches the name in the input.

So if the there are 200 column, and 100 rows.   And the "getColumnIndex"  method has to go halfway through the columns (on average) to find the column it is looking for, then...

200 * 100 * 100 = 2,000,000 string comparison operations...

As if the names of the columns in the result set changes!!!

But this is the code in an OLD version of oracle... "ojdbj6.jar" (12.1.0.2.0) to be precise.    So I decompiled "ojdbc8.jar' (18.3.0.0.0) to see if anything changed... and it did.   Some clever person at Oracle decided to add a CACHE:

```
int getColumnIndex(String paramString) throws SQLException { 
    ensureOpen(); 
    Integer integer = (Integer)this.columnNameCache.get(paramString); 
    if (integer == null) { 
        integer = Integer.valueOf(getColumnIndexPrimitive(paramString)); 
        if (this.columnNameCache.size() <= this.accessors.length) 
            this.columnNameCache.put(paramString, integer);  
    }  
    return integer.intValue(); 
}
```

So @a_horse_with_no_name is somewhat correct when it said that your problem is that the Oracle driver is old.

**UPDATE**:

For my application, I did a test which compared the performance old (11.2.0.3) driver versus the newer (18.3.0.0) driver.    This test performs an action which does a Hibernate query against a "wide" table and scrolls through the results, converting the result to XML as it goes.    With the new driver, the elapsed time was 4X faster.     If I could eliminate the XML logic from the equation, the performance improvement would be much more dramatic.

**BOTTOM LINE:**

If you have to use Hibernate to do a query against a "wide" table, or one with many rows in the results, make sure to use the latest JDBC driver.   New drivers are compatible with older database.