# Is there a way around Hibernate calling OracleStatement.getColumnIndex for each row and column?

Tags: performance, hibernate

I am puzzled by Hibernate’s behavior when loading ResultSets with many columns via HQL: it seems like **OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(String)** is called over and over again, not just once for every column at the beginning of the load but once for every column when retrieving **each and every row** of data.

In case of a ResultSet with many columns this seems to take a significant amount of time (in our case about 43 % of the total time, see attached screenshot of a VisualVM profile). Our HQL loads a table with many columns, join fetching two other tables with to-many relations (both having lots of columns, too). Unfortunately we cannot restrict the columns to be loaded, because the task is to preload all objects into a Coherence cache on startup of the system, so the objects have to be complete.

As far as I can tell the problem arises because hydrating the mapped result objects of an HQL query from the ResultSet does use nullSafeGet() for each column which takes String arguments to identify the column and therefore has to call getColumnIndex(). 
(When loading the data from a ResultSet of an SQL query one can use getString(int), getTimestamp(int) etc. instead of String based versions to avoid this issue.)

We are still using an old version of Hibernate (3.6) but the source on github indicates that the same behavior is still present, as nullSafeGet() is still String based instead of taking an index (or object containing the index) which then could be precomputed once at the beginning of the load.

- Is there something that I am missing?
- Is there a reason for calling getColumnIndex() for each column of each row of data over and over again?
- Is there a way around this which does not involve rewriting the query into SQL and using the index based accessors to build up the mapped objects manually?

The only similar issue I was able to find on the internet was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36931711/why-the-method-oracle-jdbc-driver-oraclestatement-getcolumnindex-costs-so-much#) which has no answer.
The query there had many columns, too.

Thanks for any help!

Thorsten

[image: Profile]

Answer (score 0):

This problem is addressed in Hibernate 6, which switches from reading JDBC ResultSet by name to reading by position.